# Checkbox selection in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, checkbox, selenium-webdriver

I am facing issue in checkbox selection, there id changing dynamically, so that I cant able click on that checkbox. How to achieve that?

```
<a id="ext-gen208" class="x-menu-focus" href="#" onclick="return false;" tabindex="-1"></a>
```

Comment: Is any part of the id is fixed? Also, please provide some more html.

Comment: The click event returns false, it does nothing. you have to override it first.

Comment: @ Mohamed EL AYADI, Please let me know how to do that

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the xpath below:-

```
//a[contains(@id, "ext-gen")]
```

OR

```
//a[starts-with(@id, "ext-gen")]
```

Comment: Tried this one but it is not working. There are lot of checkboxes starting with ext-gen

Comment: can you share a `HTML` block so that a better `XPath` can be given using parent or child relationship.